# How to play Disney Infinity with 4 players?

Tags: disney-infinity-2.0

Ok, so I am getting a Wii U but I want to have four players on Disney Infinity
can I do that? Because me and my friends love this game and we want to play it together.

Answer (score 1):

This [**here**](http://www.co-optimus.com/article/10716/disney-infinityco-op-faq.html#question0) tells you all you need to know about co-op.

Basically, only 2 players in a local co-op per system, but if you have 2 copies of the game and 2 consoles you can do a combo co-op so you can all play together. :)